# Connect to SSH (port 22) through tunnel opened in PuTTY on Windows

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, socks, tunnel

I want to connect to a remote server (host1) that accessible only from it's private network.

Another server (host2) is accessible from the Internet.

I opened a tunnel to host2 using PuTTY and tested it's working with Firefox (also checked that I got different IP address).

*How can I connect to host1 using the tunnel I created?*

I tried to configure proxy (to the tunnel I created - localhost) in PuTTY but it's not working.

The error I got: "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

*Pay attention that the host is the computer name in the network.*

Answer (score 0):

You connect to the local tunnel end directly, no "proxy" setting is needed.

This typically means that you use "localhost" as a *Host Name*. And a port according to your tunnel configuration.

See *my* guide for [tunneling SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty). It's for WinSCP, but just use PuTTY instead of WinSCP in section [Connecting through the tunnel](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty_connecting).